# issues passing variables from parent to child. AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to access some variables from my parent in my child MC.

**Parent code:**

```
var data_history:String;    
function finish_checkUp(event:Event):void{          
        var checkUp_stat:String;
        checkUp_stat = data.check_UP_STAT;
        if (checkUp_stat == "PASSED"){
            data_history = "FALSE";
            gotoAndPlay ("domain_check");
        }
        else if (checkUp_stat == "FAILED"){
            data_history = "TRUE";
            gotoAndPlay ("error_data_conflict");
        }
        else if (checkUp_stat == "FAILED_UN"){
            data_history = "TRUE";
            gotoAndPlay ("");
        }   
}
```

**CHILD MC:**

```
 contt_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick);
    contt_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,contt_btnOver);
    contt_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,contt_btnOut);
    function contt_btnOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
        contt_btn.gotoAndPlay("over");
    }
    function contt_btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
        contt_btn.gotoAndPlay("out");
    }
    function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace (MovieClip(this.parent).data_history);
        if (data_history == "TRUE"){
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("begin_erasing");
        }
        else if (data_history == "FALSE"){
            gotoAndPlay("");}
    }
```

Now as you can see, i have tried the `trace` method, but with no luck. Flash doesn't report any errors regarding the `trace` method, but does report the two undefined vars (`data_history`). Ive tried to use the trace method above all the functions, at the top of the script, still the same errors though.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the trace, you are referencing the data_history property through `this.parent`. Assuming that traces your value, you need to adjust your if...else to reference the property through parent as well:

```
function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace (MovieClip(this.parent).data_history);
    if (MovieClip(this.parent).data_history == "TRUE"){
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("begin_erasing");
    }
    else if (MovieClip(this.parent).data_history == "FALSE"){
        gotoAndPlay("");}
}
```

If the trace you have in there throws an error, then the property never existed on parent.

Answer (score 0):

The child movie should not be inspecting its parent in this way.

Try this:

in the child's document Class:

```
public var data_history:String;
function mouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
           if (data_history == "TRUE"){
                  MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay("begin_erasing");
           }
           else if (data_history == "FALSE"){
                   gotoAndPlay("");}
           }
 }
```

in the parent

```
function finish_checkUp(event:Event):void{ 
          var checkUp_stat:String;
          checkUp_stat = data.check_UP_STAT;
          if (checkUp_stat == "PASSED"){
              data_history = "FALSE";
              if (childMC as ChildDocumentClass) {
                  (childMC as ChildDocumentClass).data_history = data_history;
              }
              gotoAndPlay ("domain_check");
          }
          else if (checkUp_stat == "FAILED"){
              data_history = "TRUE";
              if (childMC as ChildDocumentClass) {
                  (childMC as ChildDocumentClass).data_history = data_history;
              }
              gotoAndPlay ("error_data_conflict");
          }
          else if (checkUp_stat == "FAILED_UN"){
              data_history = "TRUE";
              if (childMC as ChildDocumentClass) {
                  (childMC as ChildDocumentClass).data_history = data_history;
              }
              gotoAndPlay ("");
          }
  }
```